# Делегаты. Изменение ссылочных параметров

Tags: c#, делегаты

Прочитал такую вещь:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173172.aspx

> Если делегат использует параметры,
>   передаваемые по ссылке, эта ссылка
>   передается после каждого из трех
>   методов, а все изменения одного из
>   методов становятся видны в следующем
>   методе

Мне стало не совсем понятно, т.е. к примеру:

> ```
> class Number
> {
>     private int _value;
>
>     public static implicit operator Number (int value)
>     {
>         return new Number { _value = value };
>     }
>     public static implicit operator int(Number obj)
>     {
>         return obj._value;
>     }
>     public static Number operator +(Number c1, Number c2)
>     {
>         return new Number { _value = c1._value + c2._value };
>     }
>     public static Number operator -(Number c1, Number c2)
>     {
>         return new Number { _value = c1._value - c2._value };
>     }
> }
>
> class Program
> {
>     public delegate Number DelSumm(Number a, Number b);
>
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         DelSumm dls = Summ;
>         DelSumm dls2 = Diff;
>         DelSumm res = dls + dls2;
>         Number a = 2;
>         Number b = 3;
>
>         var c = res(a, b);
>
>     }
>
>     static public Number Summ(Number a, Number b)
>     {
>         a += 1;
>         b -= 5;
>         return a + b;
>     }
>     static public Number Diff(Number a, Number b)
>    {
>        return a - b;
>    }
> }
> ```

Получается, что в метод Diff должны передать уже измененные параметры (т.е. a = 3, b =  -2), но этого не происходит, тогда как понимать эту строчку:

> все изменения одного из методов
>   становятся видны в следующем методе

Обновлено:
Вроде разобрался, да действительно если в методе Summ изменить объекты a и b, то в метод Diff, они попадут уже измененными.

Предыдущий мой пример был некорректен.
Правильный пример привожу ниже:

> ```
> class Number
> {
>     public int Value {get; set;}
> }
>
> class Program
> {
>     public delegate int DelSumm(Number a, Number b);
>
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         DelSumm dls = Summ;
>         DelSumm dls2 = Diff;
>         DelSumm res = dls + dls2;
>
>         var a = new Number();
>         a.Value = 2;   
>         var b = new Number();
>         b.Value = 3;
>
>         Console.WriteLine("a = {0}  b = {1}", a.Value, b.Value);
>
>         var c = res(a, b);
>
>         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
>         Console.ReadKey();
>     }
>
>     static public int Summ(Number a, Number b)
>     {
>         a.Value += 1;
>         b.Value -= 5;
>         Console.WriteLine("Summ   a = {0}  b = {1}",a.Value,b.Value);
>         return a.Value + b.Value;
>     }
>     static public int Diff(Number a, Number b)
>    {
>        Console.WriteLine("Diff   a = {0}  b = {1}", a.Value, b.Value);
>        return a.Value - b.Value;
>    }
> }
> ```

Результат:

```
a = 2 b = 3
Summ a = 3 b = -2
Diff a = 3 b = -2
Press any key to exit.
```

Comment: Параметры, передаваемые по ссылке != параметры ссылочного типа.
Речь идёт о ref-параметрах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас исходные объекты, переданные делегату, не меняются.

Можете понимать это так:

```
=> res(a, b);
copya = &a
copyb = &b

Summ(copya,copyb)
Diff(copya,copyb)
```

Если вы изменили в самих методах переменные a и b на новые объекты new Number(), то переданные делегату объекты у Вас не поменялись и все еще им хранятся.

**UPD**

Опять же, все правильно. Вы сначала изменили и вывели результат, а потом вывели и ничего не меняли. Если вы хотели бы посмотреть изменения, то выводить надо было до изменения в Summ:

```
Console.WriteLine("Переданы в Summ   a = {0}  b = {1}",a.Value,b.Value);
a.Value += 1;
b.Value -= 5;
```

А теперь давайте упростим пример до предела.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Number
    {
        public int Value {  get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public delegate int DelSumm(Number a);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DelSumm dls = Summ;
            DelSumm res = dls + dls + dls;

            var a = new Number { Value = 0 };
            var c = res(a);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static public int Summ(Number a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a = {0}", a.Value);
            return a.Value += 1;
        }
    }
}

Вывод:
a = 0
a = 1
a = 2
Press any key to exit.
```

Как видите, объект передавался от одного к другому с измененным значением.